# Handle null value in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am fetching contact address in js and setting the address in a variable which I am using in html to print the address.

Now suppose if contact mailing state is empty then in html its printing 'null'.
How can I handle this situation?

JS::

```
import STATE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingState";
import COUNTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingCountry";
export default class CustomerContact extends LightningElement {
    MailingAddress;
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields: [COUNTRY_FIELD, STATE_FIELD],
    })
    wiredData({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            const street = getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, STREET_FIELD);
            const country = getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, COUNTRY_FIELD);
            this.MailingAddress = street + "," + country;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML::

```
<div>{MailingAddress}<div> 
//this is printing null Country Name if street is blank.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let street = ''  // assign a default value is a good practice, we use an empty string here

if(getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, STREET_FIELD)) {
street = getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, STREET_FIELD) //if it is not null reassign
}

Or you can do it in one line

let street = getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, STREET_FIELD) ?getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, STREET_FIELD) : ''

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample code, the problem is that you're not reading from the `data` variable but from `this.contactRecord` (which isn't assigned):

```
const street = getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, STREET_FIELD);
const country = getFieldValue(this.contactRecord, COUNTRY_FIELD);
```

Should be:

```
const street = getFieldValue(data, STREET_FIELD);
const country = getFieldValue(data, COUNTRY_FIELD);
```

Comment: Thanks! could you pls help me with the correct syntax.

Comment: here you go, I've added the correct syntax

Comment: Hi, its still showing null.

Comment: whenever there is no value in UI means if street is blank then its returning null in UI. How can i avoid this